# SQL query for removing duplicate

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider I have a table containing an id field (not auto increment). That field will contain duplicate entries. I want to retrieve the distinct entries of that id.

Consider my table is like this:

```
id    state   city
1      efef   dfdd
2      dwef   sdfsd
1      fdds   fsdfs
```

Now I have to retrieve that state ,city with id 1,2.

I tried this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Event 
WHERE  Outletid = (SELECT DISTINCT Outletid FROM Event)
```

But the data with id as 1 is coming(i.e) 2 datas with id is coming. Can anyone help?

Comment: In your example, how do you know which row with `id=1` you want to retrieve?

Comment: Thanks Dommer ..consider  which is coming first  should be retrieved,

Comment: There is no "first" in a database, same order of result for a query is not guaranteed, unless you specify `ORDER BY a_column`

Comment: Select * from Event where Outletid=(select Distinct Outletid from Event), will not work, use IN instead of =

Comment: Thanks Kamal ..If i use IN all datas are coming..

Comment: But that is equivalent to Select * from Event; :) what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554060/sql-query-duplicate-removal-help?rq=1 Took this from "Related" on the right here. It should have also popped up when you wrote the question. Also using the search function on this site is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks tombom ..After retreiving only i can give orderby..now the problem is in retreivel..can u help me with some idea..

Comment: Kamal.as i posted i have to remove the duplicate id from id column and i wan to retrieve the state and city with id as 1 ,2(for the above example).

Comment: @prakash.k what RDBMS are you using?  sql-server, MySQL

Comment: @prakash.k do you want to delete the duplicate id or just return one of the ids?

Comment: Blue feet ..I don't want to delete that..My requirement is that i have to retreive the data from table without having same id.

Answer (score 2):

This should return only one records per `ID`. The query below will return the `MIN()` value for both the city and state using a `GROUP BY` id field.  Since you have more than one `ID` and you only want to return one value, then this will only return the first record that meets the requirement.

```
select ID, min(city) city, min(state) state
from yourTable
group by ID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7466b/14)

So this works the following way

```
YourTable
ID   city    state
1    efef    dfdd
2    dwef    sdfsd
1    fdds    fsdfs
```

If we take the `MIN()` value of the city and state columns and `GROUP BY` id you result would be:

```
YourTable
ID   city    state
1    efef    dfdd
2    dwef    sdfsd
```

`MIN()` is going to return the lowest in the sequence. So since the `city` with the `ID` of `1` begins with `e` and `e` is before `f` then it will be selected.  The `GROUP BY` combines all `ID` that match into a cluster.

Then if you wanted to exclude any record that had a duplicate id, then you could just change the query to:

```
select ID, min(city)  city, min(state)   state
from yourTable
group by ID
having min(city) = max(city)  
   and min(state) = max(state)
```

Edit:

You can also use:

```
select min(rowid) rowid, ID, city, state
from yourTable
group by ID
```

or:

```
select *
from yourTable t1
inner join
(
  select min(rowid) row_id, ID
  from yourTable
  group by ID
) t2
  on t1.rowid = t2.row_id
  and t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Bluefeet really thanks...As i am new to this database concept..can u please explain what this query is doing..

Comment: Thanks bluefeet ..One more doubt..In above case for example i have put only 2 columns(i.e state and city),suppose consider i am having large no of columns means then i have to write min () for each entry???

Comment: @prakash.k that would depend. You might be able to use a sub-query to filter out any of the records.

Comment: K..Blue feet..One more thing..i tried this :select Outletid,  City,  State
from Event
group by Outletid  This also gives correct result..Then what for min()

Comment: You should place the `MIN()` around the city and state.

Comment: Blue feet ...I am getting wrong result..If suppose id is 2 in 2nd record and the same id in 5th record means it is taking the 5th data not the 2nd data..But i need 2nd data..i think i explained clearly..

Comment: it is going to return whatever meets the criteria of the `MIN()` value. You will have to review the data to determine if you want to use `MIN()` or `MAX()`

Comment: Bluefeet now i understand the concept of min()..But Min() will not satisfy my requirement,y because if suppose i entered 1 entry with start letter as 'g' and after that i am entering an entry with starting letter as 'b'.then it is taking 2nd entry,but it should take 1st entry without considering this alphabet..

Comment: @prakash.k please see my edit. You can apply the `rowid` and take the `min(rowid)` and group by id

Answer (score 1):

try this: if you are using sql server

Since there is no primary key for this table, it is difficult to identify which record to be deleted. So You could do the following

Step1:

```
;with cte as(
     select  id   , state,   city,
     row_number() over (partition by id order by (select 0))as row_num
     from <table>)
select * into #tmp
from cte where row_num=1
```

Step2:

```
truncate table <table>
```

Step3:

```
insert into <table>
select * from #tmp
```

Comment: +1 - realistically, fix the data model, then the data, before trying to perform miracles with a query.

Answer (score 1):

Insert another rowID or equivalent unique column

```
select id,state,city
from Event e1
where e1.rowID in(
   select min(e2.rowID)
   from Event e2
   group by id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete * 
  from mytable 
 where rowid not in (
     select min(rowid) 
       from mytable
      group by column1, column2
     ) -- column1, column2 are the duplicate columns with which we want to group the rows
```

The above query is generic query to delete all duplicates. The inner query will return the single row for duplicate columns (column1, column2)

Edit: Please note that above query was tested in oracle. rowid is system generated id provided by oracle to all the rows and is unique. So if we use group by on some columns and there are three rows fulfilling the condition, oracle will add rowid as 1,2 and 3 to them.

I am sure all other databases have similar concept of adding a row number to the resultant data of a query